# Как получить значения из столбца в БД?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть бот, хочу сделать рассылку всем пользователям, нужны их id, они хранятся в столбце БД.

[image: структура БД]

Что смог уже сделать:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
from time import sleep, ctime

con = sqlite3.connect('bot_users.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users")
 
    while True:
        us_id = cur.fetchone()
        
        if us_id == None:
            break

        users_id = list(us_id)
        print(users_id)
```

Вывод перевел в список, но переводятся все `id` в первый элемент списка.

Так выглядит:

[image: Вывод в консоль результата]

Если поставить 1, то уже выхожу за границы списка. Цель, получить каждое `id` по отдельности, так как отправка сообщения будет каждому по отдельности.

Comment: `users_id = list(us_id)` - зачем? По теме: СУБД хранят таблицы. Таблицы это строки и столбцы. Из таблицы выбираются **только** строки. Т.е. результат Вашего `fetchone` это одна строка из таблицы. Строка, содержащая один столбец. Т.е. множество из первого столбца каждой строки и будет тем, что Вам нужно.

Comment: а если мне нужно по отдельности каждый id получить в виде числа нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я сам нашел выход

```
users_id = []

for id in us_id:
    users_id.append(int(id[0]))

print(users_id)
```

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае гораздо эффективнее использовать метод `cur.fetchall()`:

```
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("SELECT cast(user_id as INTEGER) as user_id FROM users")
 
users_id = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

Comment: сделал и fetchall, нижу мой код

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
from time import sleep, ctime

con = sqlite3.connect('bot_users.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users")
 
    while True:
        us_id = cur.fetchone()
        
        if us_id == None:
            break

#        users_id = list(us_id)
#        print(users_id)

        print(f'{us_id[0]}')
```

Comment: так же как и было